# Protractor cannot find angular on window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I am trying to write a basic e2e test with protractor. Below is my test. I've added the console.log to see if I can access the URL, the output in the log shows the result of the call to `browser.getLocationAbsUrl()` is a promise that is 'pending' (`Promise::105 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}`). The error I get is `Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "angular could not be found on the window"`

```
describe "routes", () ->
  it "should automatically redirect to / when location hash/fragment is empty", () ->

    browser.navigate 'index.html'
    console.log browser.getLocationAbsUrl()
    expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toBe '/'
```

My config file is simple:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000',
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  troubleshoot: true,
  specs: ['app/spec/e2e/**/*.coffee']
}
```

Comment: If this is really an angular application, on which tag the `ng-app` is defined?

Comment: on the html element. I tried adding `rootElement: '#html'` to index.html, but it didn't make a difference. I also added `framework: 'jasmine2'` to the config, all that did was give me a stack trace along with the error (the same error message). Previously stack trace was `undefined`. Also tried using `browser.waitForAngular `, still got nothing.

Comment: How about `rootElement: 'html'`?

Comment: What about using `browser.get` instead of `browser.navigate`?

Comment: Also, what if you use a full url `http://localhost:8000/index.html`?

Comment: Do you use a $timeout in your webpage ? because Protractor wait the end of this instruction to continue. More info: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md

Comment: Adding a timeout like so `browser.get 'index.html', 20000` changes the error to `    Failed: waiting for page to load for 20000ms. Wait timed out after 20005ms`. 20 seconds should be more than enough time for the page to load.

Comment: just for test, replace any $timeout by an $interval instruction https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster/pull/44

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just `console.log()` different things in Protractor/Selenium, it is all promises. You should do the following instead (sorry I am not goodin in CoffeeScript):

```
browser.get('index.html');
browser.getLocationAbsUrl().then(function(url) {
  console.log(url);
});
expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toBe('/');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove these lines:

```
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000',
```